# How to implement multi-line text field using Material Components in ios using swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, material-design

I am trying to make a multi line text field using google's material design in ios using swift 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MDCTextInputControllerOutlinedTextArea multiline textfield provided by google, you can find some examples in the [google documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/stable/components/TextFields/styling)

If you don't want to use the google components I suggest trying using a **TextView** instead of a **TextField**.

You can resize the size of the **TextView** easily by using the **sizeThatFits** function provided by the **TextView**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize a multiline text field programmatically:

```
import UIKit
import MaterialComponents.MDCMultilineTextField

class MyMultilineTextField: MDCMultilineTextField {

    private var controller: MDCTextInputControllerOutlinedTextArea?
    private var placeholderText: String

    init(placeholder: String) {
        self.placeholderText = placeholder

        super.init(frame: .zero)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func initialize() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

        controller = MDCTextInputControllerOutlinedTextArea(textInput: self)
        controller?.placeholderText = placeholderText
    }
}
```

Then elsewhere in your project where you want to use the text field:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         let myTextField = MyMultilineTextField(placeholder: "Some text...")

         view.addSubView(myTextField)

         // Configure constraints for myTextField as necessary
    }
}
```